# Variables from file

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

A text file has the following structure:

```
paa pee pii poo puu
baa bee bii boo buu
gaa gee gii goo guu
maa mee mii moo muu
```

Reading it line by line in a script is done with

```
while read LINE; do 
    ACTION
done < FILE
```

I'd need to get parameters 3 and 4 of each line into variables for ACTION. If this was manual input, $3 and $4 would do the trick. I assume awk is the tool, but I just can't wrap my head around the syntax. Halp?

Answer (score 2):

`read` does this just fine. Pass it multiple variables and it will split on `$IFS` into that many fields.

```
while read -r one two three four five; do
    action "$three" "$four"
done <file
```

I added the `-r` option because that is usually what you want. The default behavior is a legacy oddity of limited use.

Comment: Ouch! Didn't know it's that easy... that gets me out of this particular swamp so thanks a lot for that :-) This doesn't scale very well though, how can I port it to a situation when I don't actually know the exact number of parameters on the line?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear enough. This doesn't do it after all - if $three and $four match, I need to add $LINE to another file.

Comment: `awk '$3 ~ /foo/ && $4 ~ /bar/' file >newfile` then?

Comment: @Peregrino69, if you don't know the exact number, you might want to use `read -r -a array` and refer to `"${array[2]}"` and `"${array[3]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks tripleee. In the meantime I managed a suitably versatile solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! $1 ]; then
    echo "Which inputfile?"
    exit 
elif [ ! $2 -o ! $3 ]; then
    echo "Two position parameters required"
    exit
fi

if [ -f outfile ]; then
    mv outfile outfile.old
fi

while read -a LINE; do
    STRING="${LINE[@]}"
    if [ ${LINE[$2-1]} == ${LINE[$3-1]} ]; then # remove comment for strings
#   if [ ${LINE[$(($2-1))]} -eq ${LINE[$(($3-1))]} ]; then # remove comment for integers
        echo $STRING >> outfile
    fi
done < $1
```

Comment: FYI, upper-case variable names are bad form for things which are neither built-ins or environment variables -- means you're risking namespace collisions with things that *are* in one of those two categories.

Comment: ...also, either quote, as in `[ ! "$1" ]`, or use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`, as in `[[ ! $1 ]]`; otherwise, you'll get bugs when your arguments contain whitespace or glob expressions.

Comment: Also, `echo $STRING >>outfile` is **not** the same as `echo "$STRING" >>outfile` -- look at what happens when your string contains, say, tab characters, or newlines, or a glob expression that matches something on your filesystem surrounded by whitespace...

Comment: Also, `read -r -a` not `read -a` unless you have a specific reason not to leave out the `-r` (which suppresses backslash expansion -- rarely a desirable behavior).

Comment: Also, consider putting a `> outfile` after your `done`, and leaving off the `>> outfile` on the echo; opening the output file only once, and leaving it open for the whole loop, is much more efficient than re-opening it every time you want to append a single line.

Comment: Also, `==` isn't a valid operator inside of POSIX `[ ]`. It's a supported operator in the non-POSIX `[[ ]]` (which is actually a pattern-match unless the right-hand side is quoted, in which case it's a string equality comparison), but any shell supporting it in `[ ]` is going above and beyond the standard (which it's unwise to rely on). The POSIX string equality operator is a single `=`.

Comment: I was sure there were things I was overlooking :-) For this specific environment and data this works, but I'm likely to use the same structure elsewhere. Much obliged, I'll review and re-test.

Comment: ...also, I'd consider `string=${line[*]}` rather than `string=${line[@]}`; the latter isn't very well-defined (trying to assign a set of array elements to a string doesn't AFAIK have precisely-documented semantics, so it's liable to change between versions), whereas `${line[*]}` combines array elements in a very well-defined way (putting the first character of `IFS` between them).